# Create Blank Space after special character at end of a word

Tags: font-encodings, extended-characters

I am writing part of a text where i need danish encoding/characters. The main language however is english. So i choose to add the special chars in textmode.
I am facing now the problem that if a word ends on a special character it gets automatically concatenated with the next word.
So

```
p\aa folks
```

should be

```
på folks
```

but it is

```
påfolks
```

I am using now some horizontal spacing makros like `\,` but is there a more elegant way? Also i haven't found a macro which provides the default space between two words

Comment: Why don't you simply add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and directly type `på folks`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add a space manually, use

```
p\aa\ folks
```

or

```
p\aa{} folks
```

To do it automatically, have a look at the package `xspace` and its command `\xspace`. You could even patch `\aa` with it:

```
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\aa}{\xspace}{}{}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add another answer to this question. You can use the curly braces to contain `\aa` to add the space behind this character, like this `p{\aa} folks`.
Personaly, I think `p\aa{} folks` and the above method works better.